# Is it possible to Use MongoDB for Lagom persistence?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jpa, reactive, lagom

The [Lagom Documentation](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/PersistentEntity.html) does not mention anything about MongoDB support, but Lagom seems to have JPA and JDBC support.

Can [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) be used as a JPA interface between MongoDB & Lagom?

[ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) driver is one good candidate which even works with Playframework. Any possibility to use it with Lagom?

Is there any other way of achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lagom doesn't offer integration with MongoDB out of the box, so you'd have to roll you own.

There are two distinct parts to integrating a persistence solution in Lagom, depending on what you want. If you want to store Lagom's persistence event journal and snapshots in MongoDB, you'd need a [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html) plugin and some glue code to integrate that with Lagom. There seems to be a [plugin for MongoDB](https://github.com/scullxbones/akka-persistence-mongo) available, and integrating that shouldn't be too hard. You should study an existing implementation (like `lagom-persistence-cassandra` or `lagom-persistence-jdbc`) for inspiration.

If you're fine with storing the journal and snapshots in a supported store (Cassandra or JDBC), but needs to access MongoDB as part of your read-side, things are easier. Lagom offers [generic read side support](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ReadSide.html), and you're free to implement your processors however you want. The documentation page on persistence read-side should have enough information to get you started.